# How to Enable Ascending or Descending In WordPress Default Built-in Loop

Tags: wordpress

Can someone please let me know how we can add Order functionality to WordPress Built-in Loop?

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) { 
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post(); 
        // Post Content here 
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

I know this is doable in `WP_Query` like

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but how we can do this is default loop?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a filter for the loop separately in functions.php.

```
function my_loop_filter( $query ) {
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) { // Run only on the homepage
   $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'title'; 
   $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
 }
}
add_action( ‘pre_get_posts’, ‘my_loop_filter’ );
```